# Transform Solver Excel program in R

Tags: r, excel, database, parameters, solver

I want to maximize a one variable (sum(DeplaQ1$somme_vrai)) with unknow parameters (alpha,VDT,constVPC,constVPP,a,constTC,const2RM,constTaxi) and I want to determine this parametres with a one constraint x1 <= 10000

I do not find this solution. triplaQ1 is a database with time and number of trip per transport mod.I try to use Optimum or LpSolve but it does not work.**

`**` My program :

```
fr <- function(alpha,VDT,constVPC,constVPP,a,constTC,const2RM,constTaxi) {
  triplaQ1$u_VPC <- - (alpha * alpha + 0.001)*(triplaQ1$time_VPC*VDT + 0.15*triplaQ1$dist_VPC + constVPC)

  triplaQ1$u_VPP <- - (alpha * alpha +0.001) * (triplaQ1$time_VPP * VDT) + constVPP

  triplaQ1$u_TC <- - (alpha * alpha +0.001) * ((triplaQ1$time_TC/a)*VDT+constTC)

  triplaQ1$u_mp <- - (alpha * alpha +0.001) * (triplaQ1$time_MP * VDT)

  triplaQ1$u_2RM <- - (alpha * alpha +0.001) * (triplaQ1$time_2RM * VDT + const2RM)

  triplaQ1$u_Taxi <- - (alpha * alpha + 0.001) * (triplaQ1$time_Taxi * VDT + 0.3 * triplaQ1$dist_Taxi + constTaxi)

  triplaQ1$simuleVPC <- triplaQ1$trip * ((exp(triplaQ1$u_VPC)) / (exp(triplaQ1$u_VPC) + exp(triplaQ1$u_VPP) + exp(triplaQ1$u_TC) + exp(triplaQ1$u_mp) + exp(triplaQ1$u_2RM) + exp(triplaQ1$u_Taxi)))

  triplaQ1$simuleVPP <- triplaQ1$trip * ((exp(triplaQ1$u_VPP)) / (exp(triplaQ1$u_VPC) + exp(triplaQ1$u_VPP) + exp(triplaQ1$u_TC) + exp(triplaQ1$u_mp) + exp(triplaQ1$u_2RM) + exp(triplaQ1$u_Taxi)))

  triplaQ1$simuleTC <- triplaQ1$trip * ((exp(triplaQ1$u_TC)) / (exp(triplaQ1$u_VPC) + exp(triplaQ1$u_VPP) + exp(triplaQ1$u_TC) + exp(triplaQ1$u_mp) + exp(triplaQ1$u_2RM) + exp(triplaQ1$u_Taxi)))

  triplaQ1$simuleMAP <- triplaQ1$trip * ((exp(triplaQ1$u_mp)) / (exp(triplaQ1$u_VPC) + exp(triplaQ1$u_VPP) + exp(triplaQ1$u_TC) + exp(triplaQ1$u_mp) + exp(triplaQ1$u_2RM) + exp(triplaQ1$u_Taxi)))

  triplaQ1$simule2RM <- triplaQ1$trip * ((exp(triplaQ1$u_2RM)) / (exp(triplaQ1$u_VPC) + exp(triplaQ1$u_VPP) + exp(triplaQ1$u_TC) + exp(triplaQ1$u_mp) + exp(triplaQ1$u_2RM) + exp(triplaQ1$u_Taxi)))

  triplaQ1$simuleTaxi <- triplaQ1$trip * ((exp(triplaQ1$u_Taxi)) / (exp(triplaQ1$u_VPC) + exp(triplaQ1$u_VPP) + exp(triplaQ1$u_TC) + exp(triplaQ1$u_mp) + exp(triplaQ1$u_2RM) + exp(triplaQ1$u_Taxi)))

  triplaQ1$somme_simule <- triplaQ1$simuleVPC + triplaQ1$simuleVPP + triplaQ1$simuleTC + triplaQ1$simuleMAP + triplaQ1$simule2RM  + triplaQ1$simuleTaxi

  triplaQ1$shsimuleVPC <- ifelse(triplaQ1$trip > 0.001, triplaQ1$simuleVPC/triplaQ1$trip, 0)
  triplaQ1$shsimuleVPP <- ifelse(triplaQ1$trip > 0.001, triplaQ1$simuleVPP/triplaQ1$trip, 0)
  triplaQ1$shsimuleTC <- ifelse(triplaQ1$trip > 0.001, triplaQ1$simuleTC/triplaQ1$trip, 0)
  triplaQ1$shsimuleMAP <- ifelse(triplaQ1$trip > 0.001, triplaQ1$simuleMAP/triplaQ1$trip, 0)
  triplaQ1$shsimule2RM <- ifelse(triplaQ1$trip > 0.001, triplaQ1$simule2RM/triplaQ1$trip, 0)
  triplaQ1$shsimuleTaxi <- ifelse(triplaQ1$trip > 0.001, triplaQ1$simuleTaxi/triplaQ1$trip, 0)

  triplaQ1$shsommesimule <- triplaQ1$shsimuleVPC + triplaQ1$shsimuleVPP + triplaQ1$shsimuleTC + triplaQ1$shsimuleMAP + triplaQ1$shsimule2RM + triplaQ1$shsimuleTaxi

  triplaQ1$VraiVPC <- ifelse(triplaQ1$trip > 0,triplaQ1$Tij_vpc * log(triplaQ1$simuleVPC/triplaQ1$trip),0)
  triplaQ1$VraiVPP <- ifelse(triplaQ1$trip > 0,triplaQ1$Tij._vpp * log(triplaQ1$simuleVPP/triplaQ1$trip),0)
  triplaQ1$VraiTC <- ifelse(triplaQ1$trip > 0,triplaQ1$Tij._tc * log(triplaQ1$simuleTC/triplaQ1$trip),0)
  triplaQ1$VraiMAP <- ifelse(triplaQ1$trip > 0,triplaQ1$Tij._mp * log(triplaQ1$simuleMAP/triplaQ1$trip),0)
  triplaQ1$Vrai2RM <- ifelse(triplaQ1$trip > 0,triplaQ1$Tij._2RM * log(triplaQ1$simule2RM/triplaQ1$trip),0)
  triplaQ1$VraiTaxi <- ifelse(triplaQ1$trip > 0,triplaQ1$Tij_Taxi * log(triplaQ1$simuleTaxi/triplaQ1$trip),0)

  triplaQ1$somme_vrai <- triplaQ1$VraiVPC + triplaQ1$VraiVPP + triplaQ1$VraiTC + triplaQ1$VraiMAP + triplaQ1$Vrai2RM + triplaQ1$VraiTaxi

  return(sum(triplaQ1$somme_vrai))

}

x1 <- sqrt((sum(DeplaQ1$dep_VPC) - sum(DeplaQ1$simuleVPC))^2 + (sum(DeplaQ1$dep_VPP) - sum(DeplaQ1$simuleVPP))^2 + (sum(DeplaQ1$dep_TC) - sum(DeplaQ1$simuleTC))^2 + (sum(DeplaQ1$dep_2RM) - sum(DeplaQ1$simule2RM))^2 + (sum(DeplaQ1$dep_MP) - sum(DeplaQ1$simuleMAP))^2 + (sum(DeplaQ1$dep_Taxi) - sum(DeplaQ1$simuleTaxi))^2)
```

thank you in advance

Comment: **make an easy and minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) along with the desired end result. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls.**

Comment: So, the bold shouty thing at a new contributor is seriously bad form @AndreElrico

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a fairly large and complex bit of code you posted. First, it doesn't seem to be an "R coding" issue as it does an "R stats algorithm" question so I voted to move it to the proper SO network site. Definitely read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r here and on the new site (if this gets moved) and try to narrow down the scope (and, if possible, code) a bit.

Comment: normally I am keen on your input. This time you're way off @hrbrmstr

Comment: Shouting at a new contributor and not even specifying a link to where they can be informed about your suggestion is totally on-base (when it comes to my assertion), @AndreElrico. It's a big reason SO had to start an initiative to get folks to act like humans. I'm as frustrated as you are with the recent mega-spate of seriously bad first questions. Taking it out on this person is not cool.

Comment: I am not frustrated, by the way THIS IS SHOUTING, **this is highlighting something to stick out**.

Comment: Hi everyone I agree with @hrbrmstr on the tone, but I think this is a r programming question, if i understood correctly the OP is asking which function does general optimisation in R, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

first translate the EXCEL formula you want to find a target value to to a r-function. I did this for a very simple formula `x^2+y^2` here, this is `my_fun` in the example. Then define a function that gives the squared difference (or any other norm you want to use) between target value and function value for all inputs. Then just put everything into the `optim` function.

```
my_fun <- function(x){
  x[1]^2 + x[2]^2
}

target <- 2

optim_fun <- function(x){
  sum((my_fun(x)-target)^2)
}

res <- optim(c(0,0), optim_fun)

res
```

To deal with constraints you could introduce a penalty term. Some algorithms in `optim` also support constraints. There are a lot of more specialised optimisation libraries for R if the very basic `optim` function does not fit your need.